# how to Implement in Scheme this function

Tags: scheme

The Maple computer algeba system has a command `seq(f, i = m..n, step)`, which returns the sequence `fm`,...`fn`, where `fi` is the expression `f` with all occurrences of the symbol `i` replaced by the numeric value of `i` in the sequence of integers from `m` to `n`. Implement a scheme function `(seq f (start step end))`, and produces a list of values (`f(start)`,`f(start+step)`,...,`f(start+n*step)`), where n is the largest integer such that `start+n*step <= end` and `start+(n+1)*step > end`.

I thought this would work: `(seq (lambda (x) (* x x)) '(0 2 7))` => `(0 4 16 36)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic solution to this is to implement `iota` and `map`, and combine the two:

- `iota` generates a list of numbers given the start, stop, and step
- `map` invokes a given function on all the elements of the given list, and returns a new list containing the returned values

You have to write those functions, but once you have, your `seq` function is a simple matter of piecing the two together.